# Блокируются макросы при наличии выделенного текста в ячейке

Tags: excel, vba

В приложении *Word* я создал макрос для работы с выделенным текстом. Хочу сделать то же самое и в *Excel* для аналогичных действий при работе с выделенным текстом в ячейке.

Однако, если выделить текст в одной из ячеек, то кнопка макросов на тулбаре тут же деактивируется и использовать макросы невозможно. То же самое, если назначить макросу сочетание клавиш - они не срабатывают, если имеется выделенный текст.

Для чего это нужно?

При наборе текста часто приходится менять языковую раскладку, вследствие чего из-за несвоевременной смены, русский текст набирается в английской раскладке (или наоборот). Чтобы не перенабирать, написал простой макрос. В *Word* все работает, а вот c *Excel* проблема. Ячейки таблиц - это в основном текст, но менять нужно только его часть. Вот собственно и вся проблема. Знаю, что есть соответствующие программы, но меня они не устраивают.

В чем состоит проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Не проблема, а штатный режим работы.

Если "провалились" в ячейку - это режим редактирования. И неважно, текст выделен или нет. При редактировании можно выделять значение или его часть, менять форматирование... Но до окончания редактирования ни макросы, ни другие действия на листе, которые не касаются редактируемой ячейки, не могут выполняться - *Excel* ждет окончания изменений в ячейке. А окончание - выход из ячейки.

Меняйте подход к решению.

Можно запустить процедуру замены символов в выделенном диапазоне ячеек. Вариант не подойдет, если при этом возможны нежелательные изменения (например, в текстах присутствует и латиница, и кириллица)

Вариант более трудоемкий: при обнаружении "неисправности" копировать в другой диапазон фрагменты, которые необходимо изменить, и работать уже с этим диапазоном. Макрос произведет замены и сам вернет исправленные тексты в исходные ячейки.

Третий вариант: набирать текст в *Word*, переносить готовое в *Excel*.

Не стоит забывать: *Excel* - мощный аналитический инструмент, табличный процессор. У него не может быть всех возможностей тексового редактора, инструмента для презентаций или почтовой программы.

Comment: При наборе текста часто приходится менять языковую раскладку, вследствие чего из-за несвоевременной смены, русский текст набирается на английской раскладке (или наоборот). Чтобы не перенабирать, написал простой макрос. В Word все работает, а вот c Excel проблема. Ячейки таблиц - это в основном текст, но менять нужно только его часть. Вот собственно и вся проблема. Знаю, что есть соответствующие программы, но меня они не устраивают.

Comment: Чтобы не рвать ответ на части, дополнил Ваше стартовое сообщение текстом из примечания и дополнил свой ответ. Примечание можно удалить.